# How to properly take off a band-aid?

Tags: personal-care, safety

I get injured a lot more than an average person. So I use band-aids pretty often. But everytime I take it off, it takes all of the hairs stuck to it and is very painful in addition to leaving a permanent scar because of the hair being pulled from it's roots. Can anyone tell me how to avoid this problem? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a correct method to take it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rub baby oil (or mineral oil) into the Band-Aid, especially on the adhesive face, as you are taking it off. Then remove it slowly. The oil will neutralize the adhesive, and the Band-Aid should slide right off (leaving your hairs where they belong!).

Answer (score 0):

Put your (say hand) in warm water for a minute. The band aid will come off easily.

If it's more inaccessible part of the body, wet a towel and place it on your body, and then try to remove the band aid